# How can I pervent Swagger generating ResponseEntity and generating the real data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am using this code to show information in Swagger.

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "show code")
    @GetMapping("/showActivationCode")
    @ApiResponses(
            {
                    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Not login"),
            })
    public ResponseEntity showActivationCode() {
        if (session.getAttribute("isAdmin") == "1") {
            return ResponseEntity.status(200).body(userService.getActiveCode());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(403).body("Not login");
        }
    }
```

And when if goes true, it will return a `ActiveCode` array.

```
    public List<ActiveCode> getActiveCode() {
        return activeCodeDao.getActiveCodeListDao();
    }
```

And I am expecting Swagger show like this:

```
[
{
  "code": "string",
  "isAdmin": "string",
  "name": "string",
}
]
```

But now it show like this

```
{
  "body": {},
  "statusCode": "ACCEPTED",
  "statusCodeValue": 0
}
```

There is no information provided by Swagger.

If I am going to change the code like this:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "show code")
    @GetMapping("/showActivationCode")
    @ApiResponses(
            {
                    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Not login"),
            })
    public List<ActiveCode> showActivationCode() {
        if (session.getAttribute("isAdmin") == "1") {
            return userService.getActiveCode();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It is actually showing as I expected, but I can't customize the Http code in `ResponseEntity`. So it can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize the HTTP code in `ResponseEntity`, you must return a `ResponseEntity` object.

in your first block of code the swagger display like that because you didn't specify any type for `ResponseEntity`. I can understand that you want to use a dynamic response between a list or a message string but I didn't think that was good practice.

You could try something like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<ActiveCode>> showActivationCode() {
  if (session.getAttribute("isAdmin") == "1") {
    return ResponseEntity.status(200).body(userService.getActiveCode());
  }
  else {
    return ResponseEntity.status(403).body(Collections.emptyList());
    or
    return ResponseEntity.status(403).body(null);
  }
}
```

the response in swagger then will be similar to this I guess

```
{
  "body": {
    [
      {
        "code": "string",
        "isAdmin": "string",
        "name": "string",
      }
    ]
  },
  "statusCode": "ACCEPTED",
  "statusCodeValue": 0
}
```

Comment: It like this (in swagger3)
```
    [
      {
        "code": "string",
        "isAdmin": "string",
        "name": "string",
      }
    ]
```
and it goes well.